# Can’t uninstall infragistics. Can’t find gacutil

Tags: windows, infragistics, uninstallation, gacutil

Am trying to uninstall infragistics, but i get an error at the end of the uninstall saying 'Windows cannot find gacutil. Make sure you typed the name correctly and then try again'. I navigate to this path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools' and the gacutil file is there. Any idea on these? Am stuck with infragistics and i can’t uninstall them.

Comment: A quick work around is to temporarily copy gacutil.exe under c:\windows, then uninstall Infragistics. Don't forget to remove gacutil.exe afterwards.

Comment: Is that path included in your %PATH% environment?

Comment: Ive added it to the PATH but it didnt do anything. What David suggested worked once. Then i reinstalled it cuz i wanted to try something, and now i cant get it uninstall again, with gacutil in windows folder.

Comment: That's the location of gacutil for VS2012.  Earlier versions used a different path.  So some odds that this Infragistics uninstaller isn't smart enough yet about finding the proper new location.  Otherwise fairly typical for Infragistics, it is forever troublesome.  Use the vendor's support resources to find help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reference gacutil as a command you need to add the location of `gacutil.exe` to your environmental variables.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
```

[image: How to add the environmental variable.]

Comment: this didnt work wither m8. I ended up downgrading to win7. Not to fix this problem, but to fix another issue i had with infragistic licenses, and this is also fixed. Thank you for the replies anw

Comment: @AntonisLambrianides Could you please tell us what issue you have experienced with the licenses under W8?

Comment: A few weeks ago i upgraded my laptop to win8, and i installed all i needed to work vb, crystal reports, infragistics and oracle db on vstudio. When i opened my project and went to the pages that included infragistics ultragrids they werent loaded and when i run the program i had errors that no license found. I did a couple of things but none worked. Here is the link to the thread i made to infragistics forums in case anyone wants to see the solutions that people suggested to me. http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/80446.aspx